# Gravity form built in Captcha

Tags: php, jquery, css, plugin-gravity-forms, captcha

I am using gravity form built in CAPTCHA and it is not working with my theme. I have active wordpress default theme and CAPTCHA was working with default theme.
So there is only conflict with my theme.
This is all i have already tried
I have create there an empty template which only contain a test form short code just to make sure that no script, ajax and style can load on my page. Here is my test page
http://pacificamedia.com/test

I have installed there a gravity add on for captcha and that captcha was working on my theme but the problem is that my client is asking for default captcha.
I will appreciate if someone can check this page. It will be great help for me because i would not able to figure out issue for last 2 days.

Comment: You can post this one on http://stackoverflow.com/ or Post gravity forum but not here. It's a off-topic here to talk about third party plugin.

Comment: Did you solve this issue, let me know I can take a look,.